# Accessing Java class objects in user task in jbpmn

Tags: java, jbpm

I have created jbpmn workflow to create workitem and intention is that need to assign task to individual user, can anybody please tell me how i can access any java class objects inside user task of jbpmn?

Comment: I have done this in our application, but it does not use the jbpm console. You can assign any variable as parameters in human task, but I'm not sure if the jbpm console can access it or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can always access java objects by passing as parameter to jBPM process and use it in jBPM process.
To assign dynamic user you can pass variable from java file.
If your requirement is to use that changed value in java file too, you can always use global object(shared between java file and jBPM process).

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to assign task to user.

1. Add user in `Actors` in properties of task.
2. Add through java code: After getting task in code user dynamically
   as below.

   ```
   task.getPeopleAssignments().getPotentialOwners()
               .add(new User(assignTo));
   ```